# How to display all branches on GitLab CE 9.0.0?

Tags: gitlab

I'm using GitLab CE 9.0.0 on the premises.
I found not all branches showing up on `Project > Repository > Branches`.

I pushed the branch which has name b1 to b21 and also the repo has master branch. (I should b01 to b21, sorry)
In this context, `master` and `b9` do not come up on Branches.

This is just only Branches page's problem because I can see the all branches in other pages, for example branch pull down button on `Project > Repository > Files`.

Is there any default branch display count limit setting? I'm administrator of it, so if it has, I can change it.

I also posted this question on the Gitter of GitLab.
If I could get the answer on it, I will update here too.

https://gitter.im/gitlabhq/gitlabhq?at=58e4c52e8bb56c2d1179060e

Thanks,

Additional notes, in GitLab 8.x (not sure, but maybe 8.12 or 8.17), I can see all the branches on that page.

Comment: Is there privileged user to create new tag(over 1500 reputations)? If you so, please create new tag `gitlab-9` and attach to this question. There are `gitlab-7` and `gitlab-8` tags, but `gitlab-9` is not yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's a bug related to pagination not being displayed. It's supposed to be fixed in `9.0.1` (see [changelog](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#901-2017-03-28)).

Issue on gitlab's issue tacker : https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/29710

Related merge request : https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/10145

Comment: Thank you! I tried to search on issue list, but I could not find it by myself. Okay, then I'll try to update 9.0.1 or later. Thank you for your answer.